# 1920x1080 resolution not in the options after connecting external monitor on 2015 Macbook air running El Captain

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution, vga-adapter

I connected MacBook Air 2015 to my 1920x1080 AOC 22' monitor using mini display to VGA converter. It does not still show me the 1920x1080 option. Tt shows a maximum of 1280x768 only. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

You need HDMI connection, VGA is analog, it doesn't allow higher resolutions.